# How can I subscribe to new socket messages in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, publish-subscribe

I was making a simple client which connected to another server via Java Sockets and would await messages from that server and modify a video game it is running.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Currently the while loop occupies the entire main thread and a way to fix that would be to put this process on a separate thread. Best case scenario I would like to create a listener that gets pinged whenever the thread receives a new message and sends it off to interact with the main thread.

I was wondering whether there exists a built in layer for this kind of process in java sockets (like pubsub or onMessage) because it feels like a very popular use case. Please let me know if I've missed something like this in my search, I  apologize for my ignorance and thank you in advance.

Edit:

TLDR:
I have a main thread which is being occupied by a game and I would like to read incoming messages from a server, is there any built in way to do it besides employing listeners the manual way?

Comment: What you are describing is essentially DataFetcher here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/

Comment: As to "... sends it off to interact with the main thread". There is an attraction to the concept of "the main thread" that really isn't meaningful or necessary. For instance, once a GUI is set up,  the event dispatching thread (or a thread spawned from that) can take care of everything. Similarly if you are waiting on Sockets, the thread waiting on the socket can generally be used to process the incoming data without needing handover to another thread.

Comment: "loop occupies the entire main thread" Why is this a problem, is there something else for the main thread to do? "sends it off to interact with the main thread" Why does it have to be on the main thread? Most servers run on multicpu systems and using just one core is not ideal

Comment: @ControlAltDel My particular code sits on top of a video game which I would like to update based on incoming messages from a server. For this reason I do not want to occupy the main thread. Also the DataFetcher is a very nice reference for making listeners, thank you.